# How can I make one property non-optional in a typescript type?

Tags: typescript

I have this type:

```
type User = { 
  id: string;
  name?: string;
  email?: string;
}
```

And I would like to construct a similar type with `name` non optional:

```
type UserWithName = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  email?: string;
}
```

Instead of repeating the type as I did above, how can I construct `UserWithName` from `User` with generic utility types?
[Required](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype) almost does the job but it sets *all* properties as non-optional, while I just want to set *one* property.

Comment: See `Required` from [utility-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/utility-types#requiredt-k)

Answer (score 133, accepted):

If you check the source for the `Required` type, it's this:

```
type Required<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]-?: T[P]
}
```

The same syntax can be used to construct a generic type that will give you what you want:

```
type User = {
  id: string
  name?: string
  email?: string
}

type WithRequired<T, K extends keyof T> = T & { [P in K]-?: T[P] }

type UserWithName = WithRequired<User, 'name'>

// error: missing name
const user: UserWithName = {
  id: '12345',
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKClAlgEwC4o5hFcA7Ac2ygoEMBbCAfmNPOtokftwBs2JMpRoBfTJlCQoAdVzAAFgCUIARwCuuRBHwAeACoAaKAGkoEAB7AIFfHCgBrCCAD2AMygGAfKi9QAMgwoAG0ABTwKMwBdAFohA3DoqAkpcGh4JHklADkmaDRslXUtHX1MxBMAcgZmKu9JAHpGi0REV0RiRlw4OFE6fMwAY1cKUigNBE7YKaK85j8sHAJiKoBGACYAZgAWAFYqo0wJIA)

Comment: And if you are wondering what does `-?` mean, please refer to this [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers)

Comment: That's equivalent to `type WithRequired<T, K extends keyof T> = T & Required<Pick<T, K>>`, isn't it?  I find the `Required<Pick<T, K>>` to be more readable than `[P in K]-?: T[P]`.

Comment: If I only need this once, is there a simpler way to use `-?` without constructing the complex utility type?

Answer (score 27):

If you don't want to make a helper type, you can combine [Required](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype) with [Pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys)

```js
type User = { 
  id: string;
  name?: string;
  email?: string;
}

const user: Required<Pick<User, 'name'>> & User = {
  id: '1',
  name: 'Jim'
}
```

Comment: This is a good one, no 3rd party packages or custom utility types.

Comment: The only issue with this is that you won't be able to use `email` at all. That's why I personally prefer @cprcrack answer

Comment: @Erythros what do you mean? Email still works  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3lAUFKBLAEwC4o5hE8A7AcwG4cpKBDAWwgH4SyKb7cIWTPABtOpclTpYAvliwBjAPaUyUAK4JEJAEoQAjmryIIBADwAFPPIDWp+EgA0UAOTM2zgHweoAMlibUDAZCEmcARmcHBjcIUIApPBZIhgEhYVCyNQAzLIABTJyAOiUkmSA

Comment: This should be the common sense answer, because the solution does not distract other devs in the code base with custom utility types.

Answer (score 24):

You can use interfaces instead:

```
interface User  { 
  id: string;
  name?: string;
  email?: string;
}


interface UserWithName extends User {
  name: string;
}
```

Now you've built on the `User` type, but overwritten the `name` property to be mandatory.  Check out [this typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrOQb2QWAChtgATALmXTClAHMBuI7EOAWwgH5LraRHmyCGzjAANtyo16TQgF8iiwqEixEKDNADqwMAAsAcuxQQAHpBCl0aTFFyDWHHtP6yFhIggD2Iasic22rqGxsgAvPbE2MhklADkZHFEckA) - a `UserWithName` that doesn't have a name property will error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is an interesting alternative but I was looking for a method using a generic utility type because I don't really want to declare a different functional type, if that makes sense.

Comment: i got:
 is not assignable to type ... with 'exactOptionalPropertyTypes: true'. Consider adding 'undefined' to the types of the target's properties

Answer (score 20):

I think this is simpler and works pretty well. Given the `User` type of which you want to make the `name` property non-optional:

```
type User = { 
  id: string;
  name?: string;
  email?: string;
}
```

**To create a named interface:**

```
interface UserWithName extends User {
  name: NonNullable<User['name']>
}
let personWithName1: UserWithName;
```

**To create a named type:**

```
type UserWithName = User & {
  name: NonNullable<User['name']>
}
let personWithName2: UserWithName;
```

**To create an anonymous type:**

```
let personWithName3: User & { name: NonNullable<User['name']> }
```

I like this approach because you don't need to define a new Generic, but you will still benefit from being able to freely change the type of the `name` property in `User`, and you will also be shown an error if you ever change the name itself of the `name` property.

In case you don't fully understand what's going on, I'm using:

- The built-in [NonNullable utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype).
- [Lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) for getting the type of a property.
- [Intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types) for extending a type (alternative to the `extends` keyword that only works for named interfaces).

Comment: very nice: using NonNullable is most explicit! Also thank you for providing the 3 ways to declare the modified type, it is useful to see those side by side.

Answer (score 7):

I improved on the suggestion made at the top.

```
type Required<T, K extends keyof T> = T & { [P in K]-?: T[P] }

type WithRequired<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>> & Required<T, K>
```

now you can require multiple properties at once

```
interface foo {x?: number, y?: String}

WithRequired<foo, 'x' | 'y'>
```

every property is now required

Comment: Thanks for the addition, but the syntax ```WithRequired<foo, 'x' | 'y'>``` also works with the accepted answer, and it is simpler: it does not need to use ```Exclude```

Answer (score 6):

For those looking for an answer that uses utility types, this should work

```
type WithRequiredProp<Type, Key extends keyof Type> = Type & Required<Pick<Type, Key>>;
```

Comment: Thanks, one more solution! And it works: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgJQgRwK5wE4QCYAK2A9mADwAq4EANFANIQhQQAewEAdngM5QDWTYgDMoVSAD4oAXigB5ALYJK1OoxBSAZFCipMOfGQJwAxvxWQ1TCRIDcAWABQT0JCgBVHhGwyoAbygnHTg8AC4oHmBsOE4AcwdHHU4AQwUIAH5wyOi4hJ0IBWS4ABtMiKiY+KcAXycXag8vbHgkADlU6FkWlHQsXEISck9vOgByFLTRiTrHE2JOSKgMcOHmhER2tN8AkPCAIgBGACYAZj2oaoSgA

Comment: You don't have to write `Omit<Type, Key>`, you can simply write `Type` cause the `&` operator will overwrite all key value pairs

Answer (score 3):

If you need to make a nested property mandatory, an intersection is your friend. Works with both interfaces and types.

```
// This can be a type too
interface User {
  id: string
  properties: {
    name?: string
    email?: string
  }
}

// Make properties.name mandatory
type UserWithEmail = User & { properties: { name: string } }
```

Comment: thank you, I like this approach too.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `SetRequired<Obj, 'key1' | 'key2'>` as [implemented here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/set-required.d.ts) in [type-fest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/type-fest).

Comment: A useful package makes for a valid solution. I did not know about this package, thank you for the response.

Comment: You're welcome! Sindre Sorhus has many great packages. It's worth scrolling through the list from time to time. Maybe you might find some other useful stuff. https://github.com/sindresorhus?tab=repositories