# Remap property?: string to property: string | null

Tags: typescript

I need to transform the interface:

```
interface A {
   url?: string;
}
```

to:

```
interface A {
   url: string | null;
}
```

I have enforced in my project to never use the optional type, however there are libraries which expose interfaces like `interface A` and I need to transform them in my own interfaces when I use them to keep the structure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make one property non-optional in a typescript type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69327990/how-can-i-make-one-property-non-optional-in-a-typescript-type)

Comment: Yes, but at least I can not have it in my classes. Which saves a lot of issues.

Comment: Yeah that comment was directed at the way you originally wrote it. The way it currently reads is fine and makes a lot more sense: there are plenty of times you want to strengthen a guarantee. It's still a dupe though.

Comment: @JaredSmith it is in the right direction but I don't know how to abstract it as a generic type/function. I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66252656/3379839 and Optional from Sequilize as examples as well.

Comment: You don't have to. There's already a utility type called `Required` built in to TS and mentioned in the top answer on that linked dupe. But converting to use `null` instead of `undefined` doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: For example - next-auth exports the AdapterAccount interface which has some properties marked as `?: string` (access_token?: string; for example). I have a model AdapterAccountDatabaseModel which represents an AdapterAccount. In my DB I use null for any value which is empty (mysql) - so my AdapterAccountDatabaseModel differs from the AdapterAccount and I want a function to easily transform from access_token?: string; to access_token: string | null;. I hope this makes it clear.

Comment: Yes, you should edit that use case into the question itself, I'm removing my vote to close it as a duplicate of the other.

Comment: You can't make a just function that would work for every type - if the property is optional and it does not exist there is no way to know it unleast you explicitly provide keys in runtime. You will have to provide the array of optionalable keys (this is possible to enforce to be correct). Add all the info into the questions itself, answerers can't write answers to things not in the question itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export type OptionalKeysOf<BaseType extends object> = Exclude<{
    [Key in keyof BaseType]: BaseType extends Record<Key, BaseType[Key]>
        ? never
        : Key
}[keyof BaseType], undefined>;

export type OptionalToNullable<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]-?: K extends OptionalKeysOf<T> ? T[K] | null : T[K]
}

interface A {
    url?: string;
}
type B = OptionalToNullable<A>
//   ^?
// type B = {
//     url: string | null;
// }

interface C extends OptionalToNullable<A> { }
// interface C {
//     url: string | null;
// }
```

Comment: @mp3por do you need a converter function? like `f<T>(t: T, optionalKeys: (keyof T)[])` but with array completeness chech

Comment: Could you provide the definition of `OptionalKeysOf` here?  Ideally code should be self-contained unless the question itself has a dependency on type-fest

Comment: @jcalz as seen by the code `OptionalKeysOf` is imported from a package which is available in the npm registry.

Comment: @Dimava thank you, but atm the OptionalToNullable is all I need.

Comment: @Dimava do you mind if *I* edit in the definition?  An external library dependency is suboptimal unless the question depends on it, or unless the actual definition is so complicated that using a library is a preferable to writing it yourself.

Comment: @jcalz hereby I allow you to edit all my answers, past ones, this one, and future ones, in any way you see fit. (If that happens do be not what I did mean I can always rollback or edit further anyways). Do you have some TS types library (maybe made specifically for SO) I can just copy common implementations from, so I 1) can inport it in tsplay 2) copy implementations directly from there? type-fest and the other ones I remember are far from simple utilities one I need to avoid copypasting